# ObservableCollection property initialized with a few children in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

We have a WPF custom control with an `ObservableCollection<Person>` property called `Persons`, once we add the custom control on the WPF window, the generated XAML represent a single XAML line of our custom control.

What do we need to do to have XAML of the Persons collection that already contains some items, like Paul, Sarah and John?

It's a long time we study how to implement this without success.

Thanks.

What we have now:

```
<MyCustomControl Height="228" Margin="45,30,0,0" Width="369" />
```

What we would like to get:

```
<MyCustomControl Height="228" Margin="45,30,0,0" Width="369" />
    <MyCustomControl.Persons>
        <Person Name="Paul">
        <Person Name="Sarah">
        <Person Name="John">
   </MyCustomControl.Persons>
</MyCustomControl>
```

Comment: What's stopping you from initializing and populating the collection in constructor of Custom control?

Comment: Will it be reflected in XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it to the initialization:

```
public partial class CustomControl1 : UserControl
{
    public CustomControl1(bool addDummies = false)
    {
        this.InitializeComponents();

        this.Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        if (addDummies)
        {
            this.Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Sarah" });
            // etc
        }
    }
}
```

Or better, use a view model to bind your control too, and create a dummy view model for testing purposes. Pass that one in instead of the real view model.

If you want to add it to the xaml, you first have to declare your namespace in the header:

```
xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:YourNamespace.InWhichThePersonClassIs"
```

And then use it in your declaration:

```
<custom:Person Name="Paul">
```

Comment: Will it be reflected in XAML?

Comment: @Alberto: Yes. I updated for a XAML version. Make sure your `Persons` is an DependencyProperty though.

Comment: We need collection items XAML to be generated automatically when the control is dropped on the WPF Window...

Comment: Take a look at the [`DefaultInitializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.design.model.defaultinitializer(v=vs.90).aspx): http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/extensibility-series-wpf-silverlight-design-time-code-sharing-part-ii/, http://www.ningzhang.org/2009/05/11/editing-model-default-initializer-for-silverlight-controls/.

Comment: @Alberto: Is this helpful?

Comment: we are checking it out but it's difficult to write a easy sample as ours from the links you provided. I cannot believe that there's not anything more close to what we need...

Comment: Or you hard-code it into the code, XAML, or you have to come up with something dynamic, like the link provided.